# powershell receiving job results

Tags: powershell

How can I run multiple jobs on different computers and get results back to one place?
Ex:

```
$servers=s1,s2,s3,s4
$jobs = Invoke-Command -CompureName $servers -ScriptBlock { <RestoreDB> } -AsJob
Wait-Job *
Receive-Job *
Remove-Job *
```

Will I get all jobs results?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the commands you]re running output something then you should get it back.